# Why use the auxiliary "essere" in "mi è toccata una bella fortuna"?

Tags: auxiliary-verb

> Mi **è toccata** una bella fortuna. --- {I've had great good fortune.}

I assume that what we see here is the construction "toccare a qualcuno" (and not a reflexive construction).

So I wonder why it is not correct to use the auxiliary "avere" instead and say:

> Mi **ha toccato** una bella fortuna.

Answer (score 2):

The verb **toccare** may be *transitive* or *intransitive* with different meanings.

As intransitive verb with the auxiliary verb *essere* in the OP has the meaning *to happen*

- **mi è toccata una bella fortuna!**
- *I've had great good fortune! I had a piece of good luck!*

As transitive verb with the auxiliary verb *avere* in the OP has the meaning *to touch*

- **mi ha toccato (una bel)la fortuna!** (we say simply *la fortuna*)
- *a good luck touched me!*

Comment: Hi. So why do you need to use "essere" here? Is it because this "toccare" is an intransitive verb? Also, I wonder why the feminine "toccata" is used here instead of "toccato"?

Comment: In the first sentence, toccare is intransitive, so we need *essere*. The construction is *una bella **fortuna** è **toccata** a me* (*toccata* must have concordance with *fortuna*).

Comment: Oh, I see. I didn't know that the simple fact that a verb is intransitive necessitates the use of the auxiliary "essere". Which is different from how it works in French. Interesting. So with the construction "Mi è toccata una bella fortuna", does the speaker emphasise "fortuna"? Whereas, with "Una bella fortuna è toccata a me", is "me" emphasised?

Comment: Exactly. But we generally use the first emphatic sentence *mi è toccata una bella fortuna!*. The second is used with some additional context; for example: ***questa volta**, una bella fortuna è toccata a me!*

Comment: @Alone-zee: No, the fact that a verb is intransitive does not necessitate the use of _essere_ as the auxiliary. Many intransitive verbs use _avere_ as the auxiliary. In this particular situation the intransitive usage leads to _essere_ as the auxiliary because _toccare_ happens to be a verb that takes _essere_ when it is used intransitively.

Comment: Of course! in this case the intransitive form uses *essere* as auxiliary verb, but it isn't a general rule. This may help as general behaviour of [*essere* and *avere*](http://aulalingue.scuola.zanichelli.it/benvenuti/2009/07/14/essere-o-avere/) as auxiliary verbs.